# Is ASP.NET MVC 2/ 3 redistributable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, bootstrapper, burn

ASP.NET MVC 2 and 3 are prerequisite for our installer. We have planned to install this software’s using WIX Bootstrapper. Anyone let me know ASP.NET MVC 2 or 3 is redistributable. If so where I can download the redistributable package?  I have searched through web and unable to found anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to include the MVC 3 runtime, [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4211) should do